Why realizing instances makes PC working faster?
I have to work temporary on not very powerful PC, with graphics card: Intel(R) UHD Graphics Intel 4.6.0 And I found a strange thing. Then I keep instances in Geometry Nodes not realized, it makes my scene plays with lower FPS, 3 instead of 5 and camera rotates without lagging. Even memory usage increases up to 1.2 GB instead of 200 MB.
Why is that? Is it because of draw calls?
